# Compressed zip file in php doesn't display latin characters

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding, zip

I apologize for my english. I need a little help, please. I want to compress a .csv into zip.
The code does the job but when I open the .csv file, the latin characters (á,é,í,ó,ú,ñ,etc.) are not display correctly. The UTF-8 encoding only works if the file isn't compressed. This is my code:

```
  $archivo = "REPORTE_PUNTOS.csv";
  $filename = "REPORTE_PUNTOS";

  $zip = new ZipArchive();

  if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {
    $zip->addFile($archivo);
    $zip->close();
  } else {
    echo 'Error creando '.$filename;
  }

  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    //Download zip file
    header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
    header('Content-type: "application/zip"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.zip"');

    readfile($filename);

    //Se borra el archivo zip
    unlink($filename);
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: ZIP files are binary data so `UTF-8` does not give any sense…

Answer (score 0):

Try to download it with chunks and headers should be like this.
GOOD JOB KEEP GOING.

```
<?php 

  $archivo = "REPORTE_PUNTOS.csv";
  $filename = "REPORTE_PUNTOS.zip";

  $zip = new ZipArchive();

  if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {
    $zip->addFile($archivo);
    $zip->close();
  } else {
    echo 'Error creando '.$filename;
  }

  if (file_exists($filename)) {

header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: public", false); 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed"); 
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\";"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename)); 
    $chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);

    unlink($filename);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with your code, but same result. The file is compressed. When I open the .csv file, the latin characters (á,é,ñ,Ñ) are not displayed correctly.

Comment: try to replace header("content-type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: or make this : 
2. Right click the file (.csv ) | select Open With | Notepad.
3. Select File | Save As.
4. Navigate to the folder where you want to save your file.
5. Enter a name for your file and append .csv to the end of the file name.
6. Select UTF-8 encoding.
7. Click Save.
8. Open the newly created file in Excel to view your data.